# jQuery navigation hides before I can get to the unhidden elements

Tags: jquery

Hi I've got some code which on load hides my share buttons, and when I hover or click on the share button it slides this down. However before I can get to these buttons to click them they disappear?

Can anyone help me get this transition right please?

my code is below or visit my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/)

**index.html**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">ICON ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ICON TWO</a></li>
    <li class="share"><a href="#" id="share">SHARE ICON</a></li>
</ul>
              <ul class="sharenav">
                    <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">TWITTER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GOOGLE +</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SU</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">LINKEDIN</a></li>
                </ul>
```

**js/js.js**

```
$('.sharenav').hide();
$('.share').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $('.sharenav').show().slideDown('slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sharenav').stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: Your `.sharenav` is outside the `.share` item, so `on share mouseleave`, it will disappear. You can try to change slightly the HTML markup.

Comment: @raina77ow I want it to not slideup when I get my mouse on the "sharenav"your link seems to go to the original one I created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this one a try (note that I've removed `.show()` because `.slideDown()` does the same):

```
$('.sharenav').hide();

$('.share').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $('.sharenav').slideDown('slow');
});
$('.share').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sharenav').slideUp('slow');
});
$('.sharenav').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false;
});
$('.sharenav').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/6/

Comment: Brilliant thanks thats exactly how I wanted it to work! Also thanks for the clarification on the transitions

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `mouseLeave` event to the `sharenav` element, so that it only hides once you leave the submenu.

**Example**

```
$('.sharenav').hide();
$('.share').on('click mouseover', function() {
    $('.sharenav').show().slideDown('slow');
});
$('.sharenav').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/3/)

### Update

You can also add a delay so that if you do not hover over the submenu it'll close itself after 3 seconds.  This can be done with `delay`

**Example**

```
$('.sharenav').hide();
$('.share').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $('.sharenav').show()
        .slideDown('slow')
        .delay(3000)
        .slideUp('slow');
});
$('.sharenav').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/4/)

### Final Update

Once you have added a delay to close the submenu if it has been opened but not hovered over, you will need to stop this hiding animation once you have hovered over the submenu.

**Example**

```
$('.sharenav').hide();
$('.share').on('click mouseover', function () {
    $('.sharenav').show().slideDown('slow').delay(3000).slideUp('slow');
});
$('.sharenav').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true);
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/7/)

Comment: It doesn't work. The submenu is not disappearing like intended by the OP: http://jsfiddle.net/2JuJF/2/

Comment: Still inconsistent. Sometimes it disappears, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @ColinBacon I see delaying is one option but is there no other way apart from delay to achieve the class sharenav to stay, I don't think it would be a good UI design if I was to delay it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your code to ensure `sharenav` stays visible when you hover over it:

```
$('.sharenav').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.sharenav').stop().show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.sharenav').stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion:

```
  $('.sharenav').hide();
  $('.share').on('click mouseover', function() {
     $('ul.active').hide();
     $('.sharenav').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');     
  })
   $(window).on("click hover resize", function (e) {
      $('.sharenav').stop().slideUp('slow');
  });
```

The links will remain visible until you not click on any other window area.I am not sure if that's feasible for you !

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuAvR/1/)